# Ubuntu, installing Qt 5.1.1

Tags: 12.04, qt

I just installed windows 8, Ubuntu twice because it failed the first time somehow (couldn't start from grub).

However, now everything works fine. The only exception is that I cannot install Qt 5.1.1.

I downloaded the latest QT version from their homepage for Linux 64 bit (around 415 MB). The only problem is, I cannot start the application. I checked this in the permissions of the installer.

```
"Execute : (Checked) Allow executing file as program"
```

It still won't start. I tried to open it with terminal and sudo. This is the output :

```
david@lw-gd-45:~/Downloads$ sudo
./qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run
./qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run: 3:
./qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run: Syntax error:
Unterminated quoted string
```

What am I doing wrong? Worked fine in Linux mint...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the file is not broken?
Try checking the MD5:
`md5sum qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run`

According to: http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.1/5.1.1/qt-linux-opensource-5.1.1-x86_64-offline.run.mirrorlist the MD5 should be: `f2caba7912b42d0d07fed6436252acdb`

If the MD5 isn't correct try downloading the file again.

Answer (score 1):

right click on the file
- properties
- permissions tab
- Allow executing file as program